# svn update and diff access forbidden: e170013, e175013

Tags: svn, command-line, service, tortoisesvn

using tortoise SVN and command line,
I made one batch file doing svn info, svn diff, and svn update
and one windows local service to use this batch

when I execute this file my self it updates my directory but while my windows local service program executes this file it returns E170013 Unable to connect to a repository at URL '[my repo link]'
and E175013 Access to '[my repo link]' forbidden, and no problem with 'svn info' command.

every other conditions are perfectly same: my auth, dir, repo, batch or else and just one difference is that I want to execute this batch while the local service I programmed. I even checked the url to access but definitely no doubt while it updates very well when I double click this batch file directly.

actually I know that when services execute some file normally it hides by using user session Id 0, so I programmed it to get user session ID arg to use instead '0' and it shows well on my session.

so I wonder is there any difference with execute batch directly and execute by local service program? or anybody help me some idea?

1. checked my auth (and subversion\auth\svn.simple but it was empty and same with other 3 folders in same dir)
2. checked repo url to access
3. tested any other svn commands: 'svn info' has no problem, 'svn diff' and 'svn update' was forbidden.

I expect the batch works well both by executing it directly and excuting while window local service.
thanks!

Comment: What are the exact svn commands you are calling? Please [edit] and share them. FWIW, `svn info` and `svn diff` may or may not contact the repository based on the arguments you pass. However, `svn update` will connect to the repo. I assume there's something wrong with how you connect to the repo in your service. Without the code, all anyone can do is guess.

Comment: svn info, svn diff and svn update all used in one batch, and svn info returned proper data but svn diff/svn update didn't. the service doesn't connect to repo directly, it only use batch file I made which works well when I use.

Comment: while 'svn info' works and 'svn diff'/'svn update' not, I guess there's some difference with permission between local service and not service, but the point is I don't know what that exactly is.

Comment: Try to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Your problem seems unrelated to svn. You could try if you can reach the server with `ping`.